# Angular 2 production build error. working fine in development

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I can run the following in development, but when I deploy to production I get the following errors:

`node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(39,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(19,100): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(21,74): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts(31,124): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/resource_loader.d.ts(13,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts(40,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts(42,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(35,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(36,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts(16,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(106,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(122,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(148,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(150,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2693: 'Map' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2693: 'Set' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(53,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(61,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(14,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(28,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.d.ts(10,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts(279,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts(78,99): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts(157,109): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts(227,115): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts(297,91): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts(367,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/router.d.ts(386,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/router.d.ts(408,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/utils/collection.d.ts(35,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(47,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(353,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(354,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(355,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(356,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.`

Comment: This occured for me using Visual studio web deploy. My application builds fine in my local environment, but then gets various issues with Iterable and PropertyKey types not being there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these errors are typescript compiler errors. Add `"skipLibCheck": true` to `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Uncaught Error: Unexpected value ‘[object Object]’ imported by the module ‘t’
    at bundle.min.js.. i am getting this error after build @Rama

Comment: Sorry @ram1405, its hard to diagnose without looking at your code.

Comment: can i have ur gmail  or any other contact

Comment: any idea on what it would bee

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that error is. You can edit your question to post your code or create a plunker.

Comment: may i contact u in gtalk if possible

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not comfortable sharing my personal email on a public forum.

Comment: ram022225@gmail.com

Comment: 9677181768 my personal number